# How did i implement an permission strategy accordingly with user group?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, permissions

I'm building a system that takes a lot of users. Users belongs to different groups. Each Group has an array that contains their permissions (Eg. "homepage": "rw", "profile": "rw"). What is the best way to implement that in my code, thinking about maintence?

Only users with permission "owner" could delete.
Here's my user's route:

```
app.route('/users/delete/:userId').put(users.delete);

app.route('/users').get(users.checkUser, users.list);
```

(delete route actually change the state of "status" from the user, thats why the "PUT" request). The get all users call checkUser, for example.

I'm thinking about create a middleware in every route that is protected and do the proccess their, but, this aproach has several issues to maintain.

Here's my users controller that check JWT token passed from the user:

```
exports.checkUser = function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      console.log("Não autenticado");
      return res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      console.log("Autenticado");
      return next();
    }
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

Anyone has any tips?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to build a `sftp` server/client infrastructure.

Instead of writing one from bottom-up, I would suggest you to take a look at what others have done as it can be quite time consuming to build this sort of application.

Reference:

https://github.com/atmoz/sftp